# How to disable tabBarView from swiping

Tags: flutter

I have TabBar with TabBarView 
based on data that I fetch from server I want to disable on of the tabs.

```
_tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3, initialIndex: 0)
      ..addListener(() {
        print(_tabController.index);
        if (_album != null &&
            (_album['description'] == null ||
                _album['description'].toString().isEmpty) &&
            _tabController.index == 2) {
          setState(() {
            _tabController.index = 1;
            //it must be last tabController.index but I don't know how to impelement
          });
        }
      });
```

if we click on a tab , it does not move and every thing is correct

but if we swip to third page , it has a strange behavior because the tabbar view is not disable

so how we can solve swiping problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can add physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() like the following example

```
TabBarView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: tabcontroler,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(color: Colors.red),
          Container(color: Colors.green),
          Container(color: Colors.blue),
        ],
      ),
```

full reference https://inducesmile.com/google-flutter/how-to-disable-swiping-tabs-in-flutter-tabbar/